# purpose of wx.App when just showing a frame is enough

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

What is the use of the `wx.App` class (apart from what the documentation says), when you can just create a frame and `.Show(True)` it?

When should a `wx.App` class be used, or why shouldn't you create a frame and just show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *have* to create a wx.App. If you try to instantiate wxPython classes before creating the app, it will fail:

```
>>> import wx
>>> frame = wx.Frame(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 505, in __init__
    _windows_.Frame_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

There will always be one, and only one, wx.App. Instantiating it initializes wxPython - creates the window thread, etc.

Comment: ah... seems like the environment I was using had already created an wx.App class, hence the weird behaviour when I tried to create one myself and how it would work better without instantiating one. Will remember to test things on pure python first! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The wx.App does a bunch of behind the scenes stuff to make your application work. It does the main loop, which is what waits for the user to do something and then responds. You have to have it. As FogleBird mentioned. By the way, you should NOT have more than one. Doing so will cause weird issues, if it works at all.

Comment: Seems like it worked to create more than one, I just didn't know one had already been created. But it certainly makes weird things happen! Including not catching EVT_CLOSE and the threads not terminating properly...

Comment: Oh, you can create more than one, but your app sure won't work right. I guess I worded that poorly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-classing wx.App is a valid reason when you have to do some extra functionality in your app. This applies for initiating a connection to a database or connecting over a network, loading some external data/files before firing up the main.

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        # Do some work here
        return True
    def __init__(self):
        main_frame = MyFrame(*args, **kwargs)
        main_frame.Show()
    def OnExit(self):
        # Clean up and close the resources from the OnInit() method
```